# Add Row Functionality in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image: Add Row]

Can a similar Add Row functionality as shown above be implemented in Salesforce? I don't necessarily want to create new custom fields each time, but at least make them visible when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any built-in feature in Visualforce to do such a thing. But you can implement kind of reusable code snippet for this.
 1. [This](http://madhura-priyadarshane.blogspot.com/2013/08/editable-html-grid-view-with-jquery.html) one is to add row and some advance functionalities as well with jQuery.
 2. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000963NIAQ) is some similar one which has used visualforce components.

Comment: The second one helps. Let me try implementing it now. Thank you :)